# SSMS Generates insert scripts that don't work

Tags: sql-server

I use SSMS to generate scripts from a database.  These scripts are just data scripts (not schema)

When I use these scripts to insert data into an empty copy of this database, I get this error:

```
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 27
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 27
Incorrect syntax near ''.
```

And no rows are inserted.

Initially I thought the line returns were killing it but this isn't the case.  I can insert individual rows with no issue (select individual "insert" statements and run those okay).  The line numbers aren't really useful either.

How can I make my insert script work? This is on SQL Server 2017.  I would have thought that as the script is a thousands of "INSERT" statements, it would insert the statements that work and skip the ones that didn't (show an error for those insert statements)

EDIT: I can't post the insert statement because it's a work thing.  I know that makes this difficult to troubleshoot.  I just noticed something else though.

If I copy the entire insert statement to notepad, it truncates at a weird place in the paste.  As in, it doesn't paste the entire line in.

In SSMS the value to be inserted looks like this: [image: field to be inserted]

But if I copy paste that field out just by itself, I get this: `, N'`.  The paste ends *just before* the "whitespace" character.

It seems like the whitespace character isn't printable, and that's what is causing the insert to fail.

Comment: You'd have to show us the script, at least to line 27 for anyone to be able to answer.

Comment: If there's a syntax error in the generated script, the entire batch won't compile or run.

Comment: @DanGuzman is there a way to make it insert only well formatted lines? What I mean is, essentially, continue on error. I know that sounds scary. Its just to set up a dev database for local development.

Comment: I've updated the question @DaleBurrell and Dan.  I can't paste the insert command directly.  What I have noticed is that I can't "copy paste" a character on the insert line.  Pasting it does nothing.  Its almost like I have a character that represents nothing and that is what is causing the insert to break...

Comment: Take a screenshot and post an image so that one can identify issue

Comment: I added a picture in the above question showing the field that is having the problem

Comment: @LewisCianci, for troubleshooting, try pasting the problem literal into this query in an SSMS query window and execute to get the raw value: `SELECT CAST(N' ' AS varbinary(10))`.